# Pivot Table show only rows with values in range

Tags: excel, filter, pivot-table

I have a CSV report that has fields Date, User, and Bandwidth for 1000 users per day over 30 days (30,000 lines).  I loaded these into a pivot table so Date was the Cols, User was the rows, and bandwidth is value as "Rank of total column value".

I'd like to filter the table such that it only shows users who have at least 1 top 50 (1-50) in the 30 day range.

I've tried using the filter options for rows and columns, but I can't seem to perform this filter.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some columns to your source data that determines the filter.  Using the formulae below, filter in your PivotTable for TRUE in the UseInFilterCol.

TotalUserBandwidthCol

```
=SUMIF(UserCol, UserVal, BandwidthCol)
```

UserBandwidthRankCol

```
=RANK(TotalUserBandwidthVal, TotalUserBandwidthCol)
```

UseInFilterCol

```
=UserBandwidthRankVal <= 50
```

Comment: I want to be able to maintain the rankings per day.  I want to be able to show users consistently consuming bandwidth.  This solution will give a bad impression if a user has one day where they move a lot of data.

Comment: What is your data source?  If it is a SQL DB, you can do this on the SQL side.  If you want to do it purely in Excel you'll need to create some VBA functions to do this.

Comment: It's a CSV file dump from our webproxy.  The file contains roughly 30,000 lines (1000 users x 30 days).  I found an XOR hack written by Excel master Mike Girvin =SUMPRODUCT(--(A2=A:A), --(C2<C:C))+1.  This will create ranking for the values in Column C that belong to groups in column A that match A2.  Unfortunately, Excel disentigrates when I apply this formula to 30,000 rows.

Comment: VBA UDFs may not be faster...maybe you could ETL through SQLite or some other DBMS (or JET)?  If you don't want to use SQL, you could just preprocess it in VBA and have it dump the filter to a column.

Comment: I agree, I think this task for me is going to be too heavy for excel.  I'll mark your answer as good as there is enough for smaller jobs to be done by these.